# Apache VirtualHost issue not able to run site with htaccess configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, mod-jk

I am having two domains example **xyz.xx** and **pqrs.net** and pointing to same IP.
xyz.xx apache htaccess configuration was done long back and running perfectly fine with this config

```
Listen : 80

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin testacc@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/xyz.xx
    ServerName xyz.xx
    ServerAlias www.jxyz.xx
    <Directory "/www/docs/xyz.xx">
        AllowOverride None
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    </Directory>
    JkMount /test/*.jsp router
    JkMount /test/*.html router
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I am trying to configure htaccess for pqrs.net but facing difficulties , Not sure why it is happening.Need Help.

Here is my other part of  htaccess configuration added for pqrs.net:

```
Listen : 8081

NameVirtualHost XXX.XX.XX.XX:8081

<VirtualHost XXX.XX.XX.XX:8081>
    ServerAdmin hello@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/pqrs.net
    ServerName pqrs.net
    ServerAlias www.pqrs.net


   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
   RewriteRule ^/$  /xxx/usa/index.html      [L,PT]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xxx/.*
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.do.*
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)  /xxx/$1        [L,PT]

   JkMount /property/*.jsp xxxrouter
   JkMount /property/*.html xxxrouter

    <Directory "/www/docs/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        DirectoryIndex index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is my workers.properties

```
worker.list=router
worker.list=xxxrouter

worker.xxxrouter.port=8011
worker.xxxrouter.host=localhost
worker.xxxrouter.type=ajp13
worker.xxxrouter.reply_timeout=100000

worker.router.port=8009
worker.router.host=localhost
worker.router.type=ajp13
worker.router.reply_timeout=100000
```

Please help me on this , when i am trying to access **pqrs.net** , it shows me this error message on browser.

```
The requested URL /xxx/usa/index.html was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: You are not using .htaccess for 2nd site which is fine. You have the rewrite rules directly in the vhost file. That will work. but I think your directory tag is wrong and causing problems. That should be the same as your document root. change it to `<Directory "/www/docs/pqrs.net">`

Comment: @MikeRockett changed it, not helping :(

Comment: @Panama Jack changed it not helping :(